# Chess puzzle that is hard to understand

Tags: learning, puzzles, bishops

Today I was solving a chess problem as following picture :

```
[fen "r1bqr1k1/1p3nbp/2pp2p1/2n2P2/p1PN1P2/2N1B1PP/PPQ3B1/R3R1K1 b - - 0 1"]
```

The solution given was `1...Rxe3`, but I did not get the actual benefit of this solution. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that after `1...Rxe3` Black will be winning material, as the sole defender of the white knight has been removed, and a pin tactic is coming. Specifically, after `2.Rxe3` (anything other than this recapture means Black has just won a piece for nothing) and `2...Bxd4`, White has no way to stop the follow-up `3...Bxe3+` since the rook is pinned to the king, and so Black has netted an extra piece anyway.

```
[FEN "r1bqr1k1/1p3nbp/2pp2p1/2n2P2/p1PN1P2/2N1B1PP/PPQ3B1/R3R1K1 b - - 0 1"]

1...Rxe3 2.Rxe3 Bxd4 *
```

Comment: We might need a few more moves, Ed.  Black drops the exchange by `Rxe3`, and then wins the exchange after `Bxd4`. I don't see the white Rook dropping off the board for free. After `Bxd4`, White has 4 pieces that can defend `e3` with one move. One little thing I see is that with the removal of the Knight on `e4`, Black can play `Bxf5` with tempo and gain of a pawn. The solution you presented prevents the disruptive (but maybe bad...) `1. Nxc6 bxc6 2. Bxc6` Rook fork. Perhaps preventing that is the point of the puzzle.

Comment: @TonyEnnis In the position after Bxd4, White has two pieces for a rook, and will win an exchange on e3, thus he will be a piece up even if the Rook does not go for free. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JiK Yep, you're right - I miscounted it about 5 times. I neglected to tally the initial Bishop capture.